# Use a random object to simulate 2 dice until 2 or 12 is rolled

Tags: java, random

```
public class DiceLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int die1;
        int die2;
        int roll = 0;
        int count = 0;




        while(roll != 2 || roll != 12) {
            die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1); 
            die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1); 
            roll = die1 + die2;
            count = count + 1;

            System.out.println("Die 1: " + die1);
            System.out.println("Die 2: " + die2);
            System.out.println("Total: " + roll);

            if(roll == 2 || roll == 12){
                System.out.println("Stop rolling the dice. 2 or 12 has been thrown.");

                }
                else {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I cannot figure out why my my program runs as an infinite loop. I think that it may be a problem with my else statement, but I can't get the dice to stop rolling.

Comment: Your logic is messed up. Look at the condition in the while loop.

Comment: it's most likely logic in your while loop

Comment: English is not Java :-)

Comment: @TonyEnnis wowwwwwwww nice point

Answer (score 3):

After a quick look, I believe changing `||` (logical OR) to `&&` (logical AND) will fix the problem.

```
public class DiceLoop
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int die1;
        int die2;
        int roll = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while(roll != 2 && roll != 12)
        {
            die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1); 
            die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1); 
            roll = die1 + die2;
            count = count + 1;

            System.out.println("Die 1: " + die1);
            System.out.println("Die 2: " + die2);
            System.out.println("Total: " + roll);

            if(roll == 2 || roll == 12)
            {
                System.out.println("Stop rolling the dice. 2 or 12 has been thrown.");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

For explanation, see [@drewmoore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538709/use-a-random-object-to-simulate-2-dice-until-2-or-12-is-rolled/26538774#26538774).

Answer (score 2):

@Nikola, @ifLoop @StephenC are all correct, but I think the the clearest way to illustrate *why* they're correct is with a truth table:

```
roll = 2      roll = 12     (roll != 2 || roll != 12) (roll != 2 && roll != 12)
   F              F                     T                        T
   F              T                     T                        F
   T              F                     T                        F
   T              T                     F                        F
```

Written with the logical OR (`||`), this statement is only false when `roll` is *both* 12 AND 2 - which of course isn't possible, so it's always true and you've got an infinite loop. With the logical AND, the statement is true when `roll` is not 12 *AND* not 2, and otherwise (if it's 2 *OR* 12 *OR* both (who knows, maybe that's possible in some other universe)), its false, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
   while(roll != 2 || roll != 12)
```

Think about it.

- If roll is 2, it won't be 12, and therefore `false OR true` is `true`
- If roll is 12, it won't be 2 and therefore `true OR false` is `true`
- If roll is anything else, `true OR true` is `true`.

In short, there is no value for `roll` that will result in `roll != 2 || roll != 12` evaluating to `false`.  Thus you get an infinite loop.

Comment: +1 for breaking down the issue to the pieces  like me

Answer (score 0):

It's your while condition:

```
while(roll != 2 || roll != 12)
```

In words: While the roled number is not 2 or 12. That can never evaluated to false!
Use `&&` (logical and) instead of `||` (logical or)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of do while loop

> The while statement **continually executes a block of statements while a
> particular condition is true.** Its syntax can be expressed as:
>
> while (expression) {
>
> ```
>  statement(s)
> ```
>
> }

*Let's take a look at your while loop*

```
 while(roll != 2 || roll != 12)
```

Imagine, value of roll is either 2 or 12. Let's assume is 2

```
 while(2 != 2 || 2 != 12)
         ^         ^
        false      true
```

therefore

```
 while(true)
```

why?

Because of logical OR, so as you see this loop never ends because based on the while definition, The **while statement continually executes a block of statements while a particular condition is true**.

If you change logical OR to logical AND

```
 while(2 != 2 && 2 != 12)
         ^         ^
        false      true
```

therefore

```
 while (false)
```

and it is end of the of your loop  based on the while definition.